# need help for javascript menu for "menuTrigger"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

need your help for **menuTrigger javascript**

I am making menu like, firstly display only titles but when clicked on menu icon(which right now dark grey box) it expands with further submenus.

I have almost achieved what I want, but (stuck)I want fade effect or animation effect when clicking on menu button to open menu.Which I am not getting proper syntax to put, plz do help me with that achieving effect.

You can check code on link:
[http://jsfiddle.net/kBpqa/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/kBpqa/)

**JS:**

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {



  /* --------- Main Submenu Open/Close --------- */

  var menuOpen = false;

  // Close menu when pointer leaves expanded menu
  $('#headerContainer').mouseleave(
      function() {
        if( menuOpen == true)
          closeSubMenu();
  });

  // Open/Close menu when user clicks on trigger link
  $('.menuTrigger').click(
    function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if( menuOpen == true) 
        closeSubMenu();
      else
        openSubMenu();
  });

  // Opens Main Submenu
  function openSubMenu(){
    $('#mainMenu').addClass('openMenu');
    $('#mainMenu').find('ul.menu li ul').show();
    var menuHeight = $('#mainMenu').height();
    $('#header').height(menuHeight);
    $('#mainMenu').find('ul.menu li ul').delay(300).css({'opacity' : 1});
    $('#header .extIcons').show(500);
    // $('#header .extIcons a').delay(500).css({'opacity' : 1});

    // contractLogo();
    if ( $(window).width() < 1400 ) {
      $('#logo a').html('');
    };

    menuOpen = true;
  }

  // Closes Main Submenu
  function closeSubMenu(){ $('#mainMenu').removeClass('openMenu');
    $('#mainMenu').find('ul.menu li ul').css({'opacity' : 0});
    $('#mainMenu').find('ul.menu li ul').delay(500).hide();
    var menuHeight = $('#mainMenu').height();
    $('#header .extIcons').hide();
    $('#header').height(menuHeight);
    // contractLogo();
    $('#logo a').text('');

    menuOpen = false;
  }

 /* --------- END Main Submenu Open/Close --------- */



  });
}

(jQuery));;
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">

        <div id="headerContainer">
         <div class="block block-menu-block">
         <div id="mainMenu">
              <ul class="menu">
             <li class="first expanded menu-mlid-601 menu-601"><a href="#">About Us</a>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-606 menu-606"><a href="#">Title1</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-585 menu-585"><a href="#">Title2</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf has-children menu-mlid-1409 menu-1409"><a href="#">Title3</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf has-children menu-mlid-616 menu-616"><a href="#">Title4</a></li>

                </ul>
             </li>
            <li class="expanded active-trail active menu-mlid-1107 menu-1107"><a href="#" class="active-trail active">Work</a>
            <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-1138 menu-1138"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1134 menu-1134"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1137 menu-1137"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1135 menu-1135"><a href="#" title="">Title1 </a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1260 menu-1260"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1261 menu-1261"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>

                </ul>   
            </li>
            <li class="expanded menu-mlid-1237 menu-1237"><a href="#">Research</a>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-1138 menu-1138"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1134 menu-1134"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1137 menu-1137"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1135 menu-1135"><a href="#" title="">Title1 </a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1260 menu-1260"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1261 menu-1261"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="expanded menu-mlid-1103 menu-1103"><a href="#">Current Events</a>
                  <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-1138 menu-1138"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1134 menu-1134"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1137 menu-1137"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1135 menu-1135"><a href="#" title="">Title1 </a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1260 menu-1260"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-1261 menu-1261"><a href="#" title="">Title1</a></li>

                </ul>
                  </li>
            <li class="last expanded menu-mlid-1105 menu-1105"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul> 

            <div class="menuTrigger"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
         </div>

        </div>

    </div><!-- end headerContainer -->    
    </div><!-- end header -->
```

**CSS:**

```
div.block-menu-block{float:right; margin-top:0px;background-color: #e7e7e7;}
#headerContainer{background-color:#e7e7e7;}
#mainMenu{margin:0;padding:0;overflow:auto;}
#mainMenu > ul{margin:0;margin-right:65px;padding:0;list-style-type:none;}
#mainMenu li{margin:0;position:relative;}
#mainMenu > ul > li > a{color:#111 !important;display:block;padding:1.6em 1em;font-weight:600; font-size:17px;}
#header a:hover{color:#111 !important;}
#mainMenu > ul > li{float:left;}
div.menuTrigger{padding:.8em 1em 0 0;margin:0;float:right;background:#ccc}
.menuTrigger a{width:40px;height:40px;text-indent:9999em;display:block;overflow:hidden;margin-top:6px;background:url(../images/menu-trigger.png) no-repeat;}
.menuTrigger a:hover{background-position:0 -40px;}
#mainMenu > ul > li > ul{margin:0 3em 3em 1.5em !important;padding:0;display:none; font-size:13px; line-height:1.2em;}
#mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li{max-width:9em;padding:.4em 0;font-size:1em !important;display:block;}

#menu .first leaf menu-mlid-606 menu-606 a{ font-size:14px;}
#mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li > a{font-weight:normal;color:#999 !important;}
li.current{background:#222222;float:left;}
```

Comment: you haven't selected jquery framework for that fiddle.

Comment: you an select jquery 1.9.1

Comment: Is any one to help me with this???

Comment: did you check your fiddle? that fiddle is not working as you explained. you haven't even added query in the fiddle.. you've to show some effort..once you fix it, you'll get help

Comment: ok now i have updated fiddle, plz check and help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slideDown()` or `slideUp()` instead of `hide()` function. And you can user [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) instead of `.dealy(500).css({opacity:1})` . To make your animation more smooth you can you [easing](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html) in jquery for most of the functions.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBpqa/2/)

Comment: thanks mate, this was exactly how I want, for fadeIn() can give another demo in fiddle...

Comment: actually still i want smooth slidedown

Comment: Just replace `slideDown()` to `fadeIn()` and `slideUp()`  to `fadeOut`. In my opinion use `slideDown()` that looks more cool here. and for easing `.fadeIn({easing:'easeInQuad'})` and to use easing you should add this jquery plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.easing/ , If this answer is helped you +1 is very much appreciated

Comment: @Shanoop I would suggest `.slideToggle()`

Comment: I have tried but, telling that "votes up requires 15 reputation"

Comment: @user3423283 Ho yeah. I didn't notice that.. anyway you can gain reputation and knowledge through questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `slideToggle()` for this. check this fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/kBpqa/3/)

```
 $('#mainMenu').find('ul.menu li ul').slideToggle('slow');
```